# Why is my function "missing argument lists"?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure what I've done wrong in my project. I have two files, an airports.h header file and a main source file. In the main source file I have

```
string code,name;
int deptax, conntime;
cin >> code >> name >> deptax >> conntime;
Airport myAirport(code,name,deptax,conntime);
cout << myAirport.getCode << endl;
```

and in the airports.h header file I have

```
class Airport{
public:
    Airport(string code, string name, int departureTax, int connectionTime)
        :code(code),
        name(name),
        departureTax(departureTax),
        connectionTime(connectionTime)
    {...}

    string getCode(){
        return code;
    }//then getName, getDepTax, getConnTime...
}
```

When I run the main source file, I get the error "error C3867: 'Airport::getCode': function call missing argument list; use '&Airport::getCode' to create a pointer to member" which is in line 5 up there.

I'm a beginner so I'm not sure why it's telling me to do this. Shouldn't .getCode() work how it's written? When I looked for previous solutions to this online, the solution was always something that was unrelated to the "pointer to member" error, so I think I may simply be using c++ in a way that it's not meant to be used.

Comment: All function calls in C++ require parenthesis, even with no args:  `myAirport.getCode()`.

Comment: "Shouldn't `.getCode()` work how it's written?" Yes it would, if you'd written that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cout << myAirport.getCode() << endl;
```

Note the parenthesis needed to call the function. The reason for requiring the () to be there is that a function named without them actually has a valid meaning and it is quite different to calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your function

```
myAirport.getCode()
```

instead of

```
myAirport.getCode
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the () in the

```
cout << myAirport.getCode << endl;
```

after getCode ,should be getCode()